# phpMailer not sending emails with no errors

Tags: phpmailer

I'm having this issue regarding sending emails using phpMailer
My code is

```
 public function sendEmailNovoUtilizador($nome, $email){
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'xxxxx.xxxxxxx.pt';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.edu.pt';
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.edu.pt', 'Diretor');
    $mail->addAddress($email, 'Novo utilizador');
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Registo de um novo utilizador';
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Body = "
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Novo Utilizador</h1>
            <p>Seguem os seus dados</p>
            <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><strong>Nome:</strong></td>
            <td>$nome</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
            <td>$email</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Aguarde a validação por parte do Diretor</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Equipa ESMAIOR.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Obrigado</p>
            </body>
            </html>";
    $mail->addAttachment('../img/logo_pdf.jpg');
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

Error i get when i log into my server

```
    Delivery Event Details
Event: failure
User: ebspma
Domain: xxxx.edu.pt
Sender: xxxxxx@xxxx.edu.pt
Sent Time: Sep 2, 2016 10:56:22 PM
Sender Host: xxxxxx.edu.pt
Sender IP: 109.71.40.19
Authentication: dovecot_login
Spam Score: 0
Recipient: xxxxxxx@gmail.com
Delivery User:
Delivery
Domain:
Delivered To:
Router: smarthost_cleanmx_regular
Transport: remote_smtp_cleanmx_smart_regular
Out Time: Sep 2, 2016 10:56:22 PM
ID: 1bfwS2­002VOU­Q4
Delivery Host: smtp.cleanmx.pt
Delivery IP: 130.185.80.200
Size: 6.52 KB
Result:
DHE­RSA­AES256­SHA:256 CV=yes DN="/OU=Domain Control
Validated/CN=*.cleanmx.pt": SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:
<xxxxxx@xxxxx.edu.pt> SIZE=7818: 550­ Verification failed for
<xxxxxx@xxxx.edu.pt>\n550­Previous (
```

What's wrong, it seems it connect but can't delivery? This is what i get from my server log in email delivery

Comment: I'm suspicious of that 535 at the start of your debug block. That is the code for an auth fail.

Comment: Thanks....but where he comes from?? don't get it

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug = 2` to see what the server is saying. Know that the debug output lines after `AUTH LOGIN` contain your login & password, easily decoded

Comment: check update with $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

Comment: I don't see a 535 this time, rather the codes all indicate success or "go ahead/okay" sequences. All I can suggest is to check gmail box spam, try plaintext without an attachment, try sending to an address other than gmail, maybe try getting ahold of the admin in charge of the xxx.edu.pt mail server to determine if the message was actually accepted.

Comment: I have checked my server log and i have this , check my new update